# Apache2.4 Service Will Not Start on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4, httpd, windows-service

When I try to start Apache 2.4 from the Services dialog (after installing via httpd.exe -k install), I get the following error:

**Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service on Local Computer.  Error 2: The system can not find the file specified.**

OS: Windows Server 2008 (R2 Standard, Service Pack 1).

I should probably mention that my Apache installation is on the c:\ drive, but the Windows installation is on the d:\ drive.

Distribution: Apache Lounge Distribution (Apache 2.4.17 win32 VC10).

Here is what I've tried to figure out the problem:

1. Looked in c:\Apache24\logs\error.log.  Unfortunately, there is nothing there (no error msgs, no warnings, nothing, the error log doesn't even exist).
2. Made sure the config file httpd.conf is located in the c:\Apache24\conf folder.
3. Tried to manually execute what the Services dialog says is the Path to executable: "c:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice.  When I manually run this from the command line, nothing seems to happen.  No error message is displayed, but no httpd process shows up in the Task Manager process list.  Please note that if my path or filename was incorrect, I would expect to see "The system can not find the path specified" or " is not recognized as an internal or external command ..." command line error message.  I see neither of those messages when I run from the command line.  No error at all is displayed, it just seems to stop running after a second or two. Again, nothing shows up in the c:\Apache24\logs\error.log file.
4. If I run httpd.exe from the command line with no option flags, it seems to run fine. Standard startup messages show up in the error log, but no error messages.
5. The httpd.conf file correctly lists the apache directory with this directive: ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"
6. I manually added the c:\apache24\bin directory to the path, and rebooted.
7. I looked to see if anything else was listening on port 80.  I do not see anything at all listening on that port on this machine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks ..

**[UPDATE]** 
What's interesting is that while I was waiting for a response to this question, I decided to continue to slog through the rest of the stuff I wanted to install, including MySQL. And guess what?  The MySQL Service gives the exact same error msg: "Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service on Local Computer.  Error 2: The system can not find the file specified."

This would seem to indicate the problem is more of a Windows Server 2008 problem, than an Apache config problem.

Comment: after `httpd.exe`. If the apache console stops.Check the apache logs `cd ..\logs
more < error.log`. please check link - https://www.codingdefined.com/2016/07/how-to-solve-windows-could-not-start.html or same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035454/cannot-start-apache-service-in-windows-system-service-administration and